# Why doesn't this animation function work?

Tags: javascript, function, alert

so this code works:

```
<script>
function animate() {
    var x = 0;
    var goUp = document.getElementById('rotationUp');
    var comeDown = document.getElementById('rotationDown');

    goUp.onmouseover = alert(x);
}
</script>
```

and this doesn't:

```
<script>
function animate() {
    var x = 0;
    var goUp = document.getElementById('rotationUp');
    var comeDown = document.getElementById('rotationDown');

    goUp.onmouseover = function() {
    alert(x);
    }
}
</script>
```

The only difference is the **function**, where am i going wrong?

PS: i need it to work as a function

Comment: In the second function x is not declared

Comment: `onmouseover` expects a reference to a **function**. In your first example, you are *immediately executing* the `alert` (probably not what you want) and returning its result (`undefined`)...which isn't a `Function`. In your second example, that's the correct way to set it up, but `x` isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
function animate() {
    var x = 0;
    var goUp = document.getElementById('rotationUp');
    var comeDown = document.getElementById('rotationDown');

    goUp.onmouseover = function() {
        alert(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to place your x variable globally:

```
<script>
var x = 0;

function animate() {
    var goUp = document.getElementById('rotationUp');
    var comeDown = document.getElementById('rotationDown');

    goUp.onmouseover = function() {
        alert(x);
    }
}
</script>
```

If it doesn't work try `window.x`:

```
        alert(window.x);
```

Or `this.x`:

```
        alert(this.x);
```

Comment: None of that works :( btw i don't know why the variable x was defined in the second example, but that was not the solution either, the function still doesn't display the alert

Comment: @Ian for some reason i forgot to paste that bit, but the variable is declared, and it's still not working, even when i try to alert with a string of tetx with this " or this ' .... still not working :( dam you javascript

Comment: I think `onmouseover` is not really triggered. Your first code sent a message with `alert` during call to `animate` simply because it was executed directly.